# Mathematical analysis of e-shop

Tags: optimization, applications, machine-learning

I'm ukrainian student, studying applied mathematics in Kiev.

I have an online store and some statistics data on it's work. Also I've learned a bit about optimization problems and operation reasearch.

I want to know how to apply mathematics to work with an online store? Maybe apply machine learning algorithms to handle existing statistics? Or maybe I can use some optimization techniques? I am a novice at all these things, I have only theoretical knowledge and know how to program the methods but don't know anything about their application in business.

I would be grateful for some links, books or just advice

Reagrds,
Alex Rachnog

Comment: What kind of data do you acquire ?

Comment: I have a history of sales and purchases of each product, the amount and date. Of course there are prices. Also have similar data on competitors.